# Laravel 4 passing database query from model to controller - error call to member function on non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Confused about why this isn't working, trying to pass a database query function to my controller. I am receiving the error `Call to a member function getCompanyData() on a non-object`

**Review.php** (Model)

```
class Review extends Eloquent {

    public function getCompanyData($company)
    {
        return $this->select('head', 'body', 'logo', 'name')
            ->where('company', '=', $company)
            ->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

**ReviewController.php**

```
class ReviewController extends BaseController {

    protected $review;

    public function __construct(Review $review)
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
        $this->review = $review;
    }

    public function show($company)
    {
        $data = $this->review->getCompanyData($company);

        return View::make('reviews.show', compact('data'));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Check the `object` by `dd($this->review)` inside your controller `constructor` to make sure that the right `Review` is injected.

Comment: when I did `dd($this->review)` on the constructor and refresh the page, I get this error. `Can't use function return value in write context`

Comment: Can you manually instantiate using `$review = new Review`, try this to check the result from the controller.

Comment: outputs the review object...hmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the problem but since you mentioned you want be able to call `Review::method()` but don't want to declare the method as `static`, so, in this case, it's possible to call using static `::` syntax a non-static method declared in an `Eloquent Model` in `Laravel` using `scope` like this:

```
class Review extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeGetCompanyData($query, $company)
    {
        return $query->select('head', 'body', 'logo', 'name')
                     ->where('company', '=', $company);
    }
}
```

Now you can call the `getCompanyData` method from your controller like this way:

```
$data = Review::getCompanyData($company)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thanks @SheikhHeera! This worked, i'm still confused about the original problem, but this seems like a pretty simple solution.

Comment: Glad it helped you and I'm confused too, welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

So **review** is not an object, and you are trying to call its method like it is object. It is probably **array**. I see you provided **Request $request** reference and you expect it to be and object. It sometimes happens to me while passing values to view. Try to track type of review.

Update:

Some other things to consider are: Why did you pass Review through constructor, when it is model that extends Eloquent and it should be visible ? Does Review really extends Eloquent ?

Comment: But `$review` is the model class that has been injected on construct, how would it be an array?

Comment: Ok - it doesnt have to be an array, but please track instance. I just sad what happened to me. If you see non-object that means that it can't find review object.

Comment: I passed it through the constructor because I thought it was good practice to use dependency injection...

Comment: It is good idea for dependencies that are not bound to container, but your Review is bound to container through Eloquent.

Comment: Then how should I call the `getCompanyData()` from my controller? Wouldn't I have to make it static to call it as `Review::getCompanyData()` from the controller? I thought static was bad for testing